# Configuring service on secondary private IP which was running on my private IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, sonarqube, redhat, vpc

I want to configure a Sonarqube Application on my secondary private IP which was previously on my private IP REDHAT in AWS(AMAZON WEB SERVICES).
We don't use public IP or Elastic IP for the application.We need a static IP for the application,which i am creating with a secondary IP.

I configured the Sonarqube service on my Private IP and attached the Secondary private IP to the Instance.but i am unable to transfer the service on the secondary IP.

For the secondary IP,I attached it from the AWS console and done changes in the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:1 like DEVICE=eth0:1,IPADDR=10.1.1.2
 service network restart

(i followed the process from the link

https://dbiers.me/adding-secondary-ip-addresses-centosrhel/) .

Comment: Assuming that the ip address shows up in the output from ``ifconfig`` it's then a question of how to configure SonarQube to listen to a specific address

Answer (score 0):

You can change a server address in `<install_directory>/conf/sonar.properties` configuration file ([see docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server#InstallingtheServer-installingWebServerInstallingtheWebServer)):

```
sonar.web.host=1.2.3.4
sonar.web.port=80
sonar.web.context=/sonar
```

Don't forget to regenerate the server ID in administration panel: `Administration → Configuration → Licenses → Server ID` ([see docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Server+ID))